# Getting an array of objects fron JSON string with Json.net

Tags: c#, json, parsing, object, json.net

I am using Json.net for a project I do in C#, and I got lost looking for how to parse my JSON string to Objects.

so in my program I have a class Person that has 3 properties -
string Name, 
int ID, 
List condition

every time the user adds a person, the program writes it to a file, it looks like this:

```
{
  "Name": "fsdf",
  "ID": 234234,
  "Conditions": [
    "2",
    "4",
    "6"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "David",
  "ID": 5555555,
  "Conditions": [
    "2",
    "4",
    "6"
  ]
}
```

The function I use to add new objects to the file-

```
public void AddPerson(Person person)
{
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"../Data/Persons.json",true);
    file.WriteLine(output);
    file.Close();

}
```

Now I have a ComboBox and I want to fill it with all the names from the JSON string. and also there is a TextBox where the user inputs the ID number, and I want it to auto complete the input with the IDs that are already existing in the JSON file.

I think a good way is to parse each JSON object in my file to a Person object (in Persons array), then using a foreach loop add all the IDs in to a list which I can access later, and add all the names to the ComboBox.

using Newtonsofts' Json.net -
how do I parse each object in the JSON string to a separate Person object in my program?

*I've been looking through the docs and I cant find a solution.. also tried google but found nothing that addresses my problem. 
*I started coding again after a long time off, and I am a bit new to JSON so I am sorry if my question is super noob :D.

Comment: Basically, what you've got isn't a valid JSON object. I would suggest changing your code so that each time the user adds a person, it rewrites the whole file as an array of objects, i.e. `[ { /* person 1 */ }, { /* person 2 */ }]`.

Comment: I edit my question to show you the function I use to add the object to the file, please explain me how can I change it to make it valid. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Instead of appending to the file, you could parse it all as a `List<Person>`, add the new person to the list, then serialize it out as a `List<Person>`.

Comment: good idea, I'll try this. Thank you again!

Comment: how do I parse back the objects from the file to the Persons list?

Comment: Well, you're trying to parse it as a list... have you read the json.net documentation? You should be able to work this out with a bit of research and experimentation.

Comment: well yeah I looked up there, I found a way to parse 1 object but I cant find a way to pass all the others.. I thought about using loops but that doesnt seem to work either.. Iam sure there's a built in method to do this but I get confused with the terminology there as Iam new to JSON. can you help me or atleast direct me to the right section?

Comment: Just use `List<Person>` as the type argument...

Comment: Yeahhh made it!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!